# Using multi_match with Elasticsearch bulk scan in Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I'm trying to use the `multi_match` functionality within Elasticsearch using the [elasticsearch-py](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io) library.

Setting it up like this:

```
  res = helpers.scan(es, index="allcomms", query = {
      "multi_match" : {
      "query":    'multiple terms', 
      "fields": ["text"] 
  }})
```

I get:

> RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'Unknown key for
>   a START_OBJECT in [multi_match].')

Anyone know if there is a way to conduct this search using the Elasticsearch-py library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the query is not correct. Whenever we observe the `parsing_exception` then we need to first ensure that the query we have works via `Kibana` or `Postman` or any other `RESTful client application` pointing to the ES instance.

Your code has to be in the below format.

```
res = helpers.scan(es, index="allcomms", query = { "query" : {
      "multi_match" : {
      "query": "multiple terms", 
      "fields": ["text"] 
  }}})
```

Basically below is how your [multi-match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) query would be

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "multi_match":{  
         "query":"multiple terms",
         "fields":[  
            "text"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Let me know if it helps!